# Strcmp 1-D array vs 2-D array in c

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array, strcmp

When using strcmp function (in the string.h library) ,  passing a 2-D character array as a parameter comparison , there is a need to add the ampersand symbol like

```
&mainlist[i][0]
```

otherwise like

```
mainlist[i][0]
```

there's an error

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

versus when passing 1-D character array as a parameter comparison , its enough

```
mainlist[i]
```

without ampersand symbol.  How come?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FOUND 1
#define NOT 0

int main()
{
   char mainlist[5][10] = {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"};
   int flag, i;
   flag = NOT;
   char myname[50];
   printf("Enter ur name.\n");
   scanf("%s", myname);
   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      if(strcmp(mainlist[i], myname)== 0) //vs if(strcmp(&mainlist[i][0]), myname)==0)
      {
         flag = FOUND;
         printf("Your name was found welcome.\n");
         break;
        
      }
   }
   if(flag == NOT)
   {
      printf("Your name was not found .\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: In most situations, when using the name of an array in an expression, the array will [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471) to a pointer to the first element of the array. Therefore, when writing the expression `mainlist[i]`, in most situations, this expression will decay to a pointer to the first element, i.e. to `&mainlist[i][0]`.

Comment: Elements of mainlist are chars, so `mainlist[i][0]` has `char` type, `strcmp()` expect pointer to a chars.

Comment: <O/T> instead, do `#include <stdbool.h>`, do `bool flag`, and get rid of `#define FOUND` and `NOT`

Comment: `a[i]` is convenient notation for `*(a+i)`, (as such, `i[a]` is also completely valid.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When using strcmp function (in the string.h library) , passing a 2-D character array as a parameter comparison , there is a need to add the ampersand symbol like: `&mainlist[i][0]`

Each use of an array index reduces a dimension of the array. `mainlist` is a 2D char array, `mainlist[i]` is a 1D char array, and `mainlist[i][0]` is a single `char`.

`strcmp()` requires its arguments to be pointers to the first `char` in the strings to compare, that's all that string are. `mainlist[i][0]` is a single `char`, like `'t'`, so that won't work. `&mainlist[i][0]` is its address, a pointer to the first `char` in the string, so that works.

On the other hand, when you give an array is given as a function argument, what actually gets passed is a pointer to the first element of the array.  For array `mainlist[i]`, that's `&mainlist[i][0]`.  Look familiar?  This is presumably one of the key points you overlooked.

---

```
char mainlist[5][10] = {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"};
```

Looks like this in memory.

```
          1         2         3         4
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
test1_____test2_____test3_____test4_____test5_____
^
|
mainlist
```

Where `_` represents a null byte. `mainlist` points at the memory containing the first character.

When you ask for `mainlist[i]` that says to add `i * 10` to the address of `mainlist` and dereference it. You can literally write `*mainlist + i * 10`

```
          mainlist[1]         mainlist[3]
          |                   |
          v                   v
          1         2         3         4
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
test1_____test2_____test3_____test4_____test5_____
^                   ^                   ^
|                   |                   |
mainlist[0]         mainlist[2]         mainlist[4]
```

A pointer to the first character of a string is what a string is in C, a `char *`. Each of these are a string, a 1-D array, suitable for passing to `strcmp`.

`mainlist[i][0]` says to take the address of `mainlist[i]`, add 0, and dereference it. The result is a `char` like `t`. This doesn't work with `strcmp` because it takes a pointer. The integer in "warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]" is the `char` because characters are just integers and `strcmp` tried to use that integer as a `char` pointer.

`&mainlist[i][0]` says to make a pointer to that `char`, so we're back to a `char *` or `mainlist[i]`.

[Demonstration](https://www.online-cpp.com/JQpDY0F6oj).

`mainlist[i]` is almost always preferable to `&mainlist[i][0]`. However, it does have its uses. There are times when you want to skip the first few characters of a string, and you can do so without copying nor modifying the string.
For example, `&mainlist[2][2]` is `"st3"`. It's a pointer to `mainlist[2]` + 2.

```
                      &mainlist[2][2]
                      |
                      v
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
test1_____test2_____test3_____test4_____test5_____
                    ^
                    |
                    mainlist[2]
```

C will read from the pointer until the null byte.

Comment: Nice answer.  Too bad it includes "`mainlist` is, effectively, a `char **`".  I suppose you are trying to avoid excessive technical detail, but this particular detail is one that regularly bites C neophytes.  A 2D array is an array of arrays, and it decays to a pointer to an array.  This is neither equivalent to nor interchangeable with a double pointer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I hear you, and I struggled with that myself. However, at this point in their learning it would just go over their head. C is fractally complicated. It throws so many new and complicated things at a new programmer that one has to resist dragging them into that fractal. Pointer decay is not necessary to get a grasp of what's happening. If you have a link to a simple explanation, link it to "effectively".

Comment: @JohnBollinger If you have a more accurate and succinct way to explain it, please edit it in. But do be careful of the fractal.

Comment: See what you think of that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you, I tweaked it some. I made it clear that `x`, `x[i]` and `x[i][j]` all reduce the dimensions of the array; I think that's the main confusion. I wanted to say "each use of an array index dereferences the pointer", I find it illustrative think of it as `char **` to `char *` to `char`, but that isn't quite right for arrays.